# Delete Multiple Rows from A Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to delete multiple rows where, `df.service == 'harvest'`  or `'http_2873'` or `'red_i'`, but I'm running a for loop and going through the entire df instead

```py
for _ in df1.service:
    i = df1[((df1.service == 'harvest'))].index
    df1.drop(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could exclude the rows that contain any of those strings you listed using [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), which allows `|` (or),  and returns a `boolean`. Then you filter your `DataFrame` with `.loc` and `~` negation.
:

```
new = df.loc[~df.Service.str.contains(r'harvest|http_2873|red_i')]
```

---

```
>>> new
          Date Customers Location  Sales Service
12  05/10/2021         A      NSW     12     one
13  03/10/2021         B      NSW     10     two
14  01/10/2021         C      NSW     33   three
```

You can also include `case=False` in `str.contains('..',case=False)` which disregards upper / lower cases in case you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
df[~((df['Service'] == 'harvest') | (df['Service'] == 'http_2873') | (df['Service'] == 'red_i'))]
```

.

```
df
    Date        Customers   Location    Sales   Service
0   2021-10-05  A           NSW         12      harvest
1   2021-10-03  B           NSW         10      http_2873
2   2021-10-01  C           NSW         33      red_i
0   2021-10-05  A           NSW         12      harvest
1   2021-10-03  B           NSW         10      http_2873
2   2021-10-01  C           NSW         33      red_i
0   2021-10-05  A           NSW         12      harvest
1   2021-10-03  B           NSW         10      http_2873
2   2021-10-01  C           NSW         33      red_i
0   2021-10-05  A           NSW         12      harvest
1   2021-10-03  B           NSW         10      http_2873
2   2021-10-01  C           NSW         33      red_i

df[~((df['Service'] == 'harvest') | (df['Service'] == 'http_2873') | (df['Service'] == 'red_i'))]

    Date        Customers   Location    Sales   Service
1   2021-10-03  B           NSW         10      hello
2   2021-10-01  C           NSW         33      hello1
0   2021-10-05  A           NSW         12      hello3
```

Answer (score 1):

`df2 = df[(df['service'] != 'harvest') & (df['service'] != 'http_2873') & (df['service'] != 'red_i')]`

Deleting those rows with service which equals `harvest` or `http_2873` or `red_i` means leaving the rows with service which is not equal to `harvest` and not equal to `http_2873` and not equal to `red_i`.

You have to assign `df` to a new DataFrame `df2`, otherwise you would not get the result you want.

Comment: Please include an explanation

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the explanation, instead of posting a comment